# AngularJS: How can I pass in the ID to a show action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angularjs-resource

I'm just learning AngularJS.  I have the following JSON endpoint

`/api/v1/leaderboards/:id`

which returns a leaderboard corresponding to the ID.

I have the following AngularJS service:

```
App.factory 'Leaderboard', ['$resource', ($resource) ->
  $resource '/api/v1/leaderboards/:id', id: '@id'
]
```

And this AngularJS controller:

```
App.controller 'LeaderboardsCtrl', ['$scope', 'Leaderboard', ($scope, Leaderboard) ->
  $scope.selectedLeaderboard = Leaderboard.query()
]
```

And here's my view (in haml):

```
.leaderboard{"ng-app" => 'Leaderboards', id:"ng-app"}
  %h4.title
    Leaderboard Title
  .leader-section{'ng-controller' => "LeaderboardsCtrl"}
    .leader-content{'ng-show' => "selectedLeaderboard", 'ng-repeat' => "leader in selectedLeaderboard"}
      .media.award-group
        %a.pull-left{href: "{{leader.user.path}}"}
          %img.media-object{src: "{{leader.user.small_pic_url}}"}
        .media-body
          %h4.media-heading
            %a.leader-name{href: "{{leader.user.path}}"}
              {{leader.user.name}}
            .metric.pull-right
              {{leader.count}}
```

When I load the page, I see this error in the console:

`GET http://localhost:3000/api/v1/leaderboards 404 (Not Found)`

If I replace `:id` with an actual leaderboard ID, then everything works fine.  But how can I pass that ID in from the view level?

Comment: I think you just need to add brackets  $resource '/api/v1/leaderboards/:id', {id: '@id'}

Answer (score 0):

```
App.controller 'LeaderboardsCtrl', ['$scope', 'Leaderboard', ($scope, Leaderboard) ->
  $scope.selectedLeaderboard = Leaderboard.query({id: 'count-receiver'})
]
```

Just have to pass the ID to the service as above.